# How can I test AWS Cognito protected APIs in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to test out some AWS APIs that are protected by Cognito. I found the first part on how to get the Json token but I can't figure out how to use the token correctly so I can authenticate on the API.

Here's my code :

```
import boto3 as boto3;
import requests

username='test@gmail.com'
password='test1234567'

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
response =  client.initiate_auth(
    AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
    AuthParameters={
        "USERNAME": username,
        "PASSWORD": password,
    },
    ClientId='12121212121212',
)
token = response['AuthenticationResult']['AccessToken']

#print("Log in success")
#print("Access token:", response['AuthenticationResult']['AccessToken'])
#print("ID token:", response['AuthenticationResult']['IdToken'])


url = 'https://XXXXXXXX.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/incidents'
#print('url:', url)

#response = requests.get(url, headers={'authorization': token })
#print('GET:', response.status_code)

head = {'Authorization': token}
response = requests.get(url, headers=head)

print(response.content)
```

I'm getting the following error message :

```
b'{"message":"Authorization header requires \'Credential\' parameter. Authorization header requires \'Signature\' parameter. Authorization header requires \'SignedHeaders\' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a \'X-Amz-Date\' or a \'Date\' header. Authorization=
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the problem and it's working fine now, 2 things were wrong :

- The endpoint was wrong - AWS doesn't send a correct error message (!)
- The request has to be sent with response['AuthenticationResult']['IdToken']

Answer (score 0):

1. Please make sure you have selected Cognito or IAM in your API Gateway. From the error message it seems you have selected IAM for protecting the API.
2. Check the Authorization header's name which you configured for your Cognito Authorizer. You need to use same header name while passing the Cognito token.
3. If you have configured OAuth scopes in API Gateway side, then you must use access token. And no scope is configured then you can use ID token for authorization.

That said, you can try from Postman application for testing purpose.